# Jackson: differing JsonInclude for all properties of certain type (e.g. Optional)

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, jackson, option-type

While using Jackson in my Java application for serialisation (POJO to JSON) and deserialisation (JSON to POJO) I generally want to preserve all fields and therefore use the (default) `JsonInclude.Value.ALWAYS`.

In order to allow partial updates via the application's Rest API, I also want to differentiate between a value being set to `null` specifically and that value being left unchanged. For that, the Java8 `Optional<?>` class seems to be the right selection.

To get the proper support, I have to add the `Jdk8Module` to the `ObjectMapper`. All pretty straightforward.

The out-of-the-box deserialisation behaviour is exactly what I want. A non-existent field remains its default (here: `null`) and an explicitly provided `null` value is deserialised as `Optional.empty()` (or `Optional.ofNullable(null)`).

---

**What I want is for an `Optional<?>` field with the explicit value of `null` to be excluded from the generated JSON, but any other field (e.g. a plain `Integer`) to be always included (even if it is `null`).**

One of the numerous options available is a `MixIn`. Unfortunately, a `MixIn` might work for other annotations, but not for `@JsonInclude` (which seems to be a bug in Jackson).

---

```
public class OptionalObjectMappingTest {
    public static class MyBean {
        public Integer one;
        public Optional<Integer> two;
        public Optional<Integer> three;
        public Optional<Integer> four;
    }

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NOT_NULL)
    public static class OptionalMixIn {}

    private ObjectMapper initObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .setSerialisationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
                .addMixIn(Optional.class, OptionalMixIn.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeserialisation() {
        String json = "{\"one\":null,\"two\":2,\"three\":null}";
        MyBean bean = initObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyBean.class);
        Assert.assertNull(bean.one);
        Assert.assertEquals(Optional.of(2), bean.two);
        Assert.assertEquals(Optional.empty(), bean.three);
        Assert.assertNull(bean.four);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSerialisation() {
        MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        bean.one = null;
        bean.two = Optional.of(2);
        bean.three = Optional.empty();
        bean.four = null;
        String result = initObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bean);
        String expected = "{\"one\":null,\"two\":2,\"three\":null}";
        // FAILS, due to result = "{one:null,two:2,three:null,four:null}"
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```

---

There are a number of ways to (dynamically) include/exclude fields and their values, but none of the "official" ways seem to do the trick:

1. `@JsonInclude` annotations on each `Optional<?>` field actually do what I want, but that's just too easy to forget and cumbersome.
2. A custom `MixIn` should allow for the global definition of the `JsonInclude` annotation per type, but are apparently not applied (as per above example tests).
3. `@JsonIgnore` (and related) annotations are static and don't care for the field's value.
4. `@JsonFilter` would need to be set on each class containing `Optional` fields and you would need to know each affected type in the `PropertyFilter`. I.e. even worth than just adding `JsonInclude` on each `Optional` field.
5. `@JsonView` don't allow for dynamic inclusion/exclusion of fields based on a given bean instance's field value.
6. A custom `JsonSerializer<?>` registered via `ObjectMapper.setNullValueSerializer()` is only called after the field name has been inserted, i.e. the generated JSON is invalid if we just don't do anything.
7. A custom `BeanSerializerModifier` is involved before the field's name is being inserted in the JSON, but it has no access to the field's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Edit:*
>
> As per StaxMan's answer, this doesn't seem to be a bug but a feature, as mix-ins are not meant to add annotations for every property of a certain type. The attempt of using mix-ins as described in the question just adds the `@JsonInclude` annotation on the `Optional` class which has a different meaning (already described in that other answer).

---

## Solution as of *jackson-databind* version 2.9.0

Since mix-ins are designed to behave differently, there is a new configuration option on the `ObjectMapper`'s `configOverride()`:

- `setIncludeAsProperty()`

The configuration is as simple as that:

```
private ObjectMapper initObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
    objectMapper.configOverride(Optional.class)
            .setIncludeAsProperty(JsonInclude.Value
                    .construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL, null));
    return objectMapper;
}
```

---

The adjusted example looks like this:

---

```
public class OptionalObjectMappingTest {

    public static class MyBean {
        public Integer one;
        public Optional<Integer> two;
        public Optional<Integer> three;
        public Optional<Integer> four;
    }

    private ObjectMapper initObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
        objectMapper.configOverride(Optional.class)
                .setIncludeAsProperty(JsonInclude.Value
                        .construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL, null));
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Test
    public void testRoundTrip() throws Exception {
        String originalJson = "{\"one\":null,\"two\":2,\"three\":null}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = initObjectMapper();

        MyBean bean = mapper.readValue(originalJson, MyBean.class);
        String resultingJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
        // SUCCESS: no "four:null" field is being added
        Assert.assertEquals(originalJson, resultingJson);
    }
}
```

---

## Workaround before *jackson-databind* version 2.9.0

A working solution for this is to override the `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and set it on the `ObjectMapper`.

Just include the custom introspector class and change the `initObjectMapper()` method to the following and the given tests will succeed:

```
public static class OptionalAwareAnnotationIntrospector
        extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public JsonInclude.Value findPropertyInclusion(Annotated a) {
        if (Optional.class.equals(a.getRawType())) {
            return JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL, JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        }
        return super.findPropertyInclusion(a);
    }
}

private ObjectMapper initObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
            .setSerialisationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
            .setAnnotationIntrospector(new OptionalAwareAnnotationIntrospector());
}
```

Comment: Logged this as [issue #1522 for jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1522). Let's see whether that can be easily fixed there.

Comment: jackson-databind 2.9.0 was released end of July 2017 and included a new configuration option to support this as per the linked GitHub issue #1522

Answer (score 2):

As far I was able to investigate, the problem is not with mix-ins at all, but semantics of `@JsonInclude`. There are 2 possible interpretations for meaning of inclusion attachment of a type:

1. To use that inclusion for all values of the type (unless overridden by per-property annotations)
2. To use that inclusion for all POJO properties that type defines (unless overridden by per-property annotations)

Expectation here seems to be (1), but Jackson actually does (2) for historical reasons. This allows defaulting of all properties of given POJO easily, like:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Stuff {
    public String name;
    public Address address;
}
```

but not, for example

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Address {
}
```

to make all `null`-valued `Address`-properties to be filtered out.

Comment: Good to have cleared up my misunderstanding there.
Now I only need a "proper" way of achieving my goal :)